# How to supply a constant current to a load regardless of its resistance?

Tags: circuit-design, current-source

I am tasked with building a circuit which generates PWM signals from a microcontroller with an amplitude of 3.3V and then amplifies them to an amplitude of 12V.The second requirement is that those signals "should be able to supply at least 0.8A of current". Since they come to the effect of powering a device, I find it the most straightforward to think that I have to drive such current regardless of the resistance of the device (about which I am not given information) and without changing the amplitude voltage.

The voltage amplification part went smooth, but I still haven't found a way to satisfy the current condition. As of now, this is my work-in-progress circuit (right pane):

[image: circuit schematic and current reading]

I decided to approach the problem by building a constant current source driving the necessary current through the load whenever the PWM signal is high. For that I found a basic setup with an NPN transistor and a zener diode and built it such that the current flowing through the emitter resistor is fixed to the breakdown voltage of the diode and Re at 0.8A. And current reading across Re was indeed 800mA before I connected it to the load. After connecting it though, it showed the reading on the left pane, which of course makes sense in light of Ohm's law but that doesn't help me in my situation. I can't assume the load will be of conveniently low resistance (I think...) and that's why I am simulating it with a 1kΩ resistor.

I hence have two questions: Do I understand correctly what I need to do from the initial requirements, and if I do, is there a current source configuration (or perhaps some alteration to my configuration) which would allow me to drive at least 0.8A provided I don't know what load resistance I am working with? I would appreciate any advice, especially since I am a novice in building circuits.

**Edit 1**
The device being powered is a stepper motor.

Comment: "Able to supply" means it needs to have a capacity between 0 and 0.8A, not that it must force the load to accept 0.8A.  If the load is high impedance or an open circuit, it is ok to provide no current at all.

Comment: Alright, but then why would the requirement state "at least". The device being powered is a small motor. In my head, I picture that the motor will not start working until that current threshold and will from then on operate at that power determined by the current through it. I am not sure if that's correct reasoning.

Comment: "should be able to supply at least 0.8A of current" literally means that it must be capable of supplying 800mA. The key words here being "should be able to" - not "must". Your spec is telling you that your stepper could draw as much as 800mA, and your supply needs to be *able to* supply that current, not that it must force that current through the stepper.

Comment: Note that the output current requirement affects component selection.  A 2N2222 is not rated for 800 mA of collector current, nor for the subsequent power dissipation in the device.  It will work fine in a simulation program, but burn up IRL.

Comment: @Dimistov From your description this just sounds like a voltage level translator. Why are you forcing yourself to think in terms of driving a current? Or am I just not reading you very well?

Comment: **Q:** "Why would the requirement state, 'at least'?" **A:** Because it would be acceptable if the output was _able_ to supply more than 0.8A.

Comment: You don;t have the regulate the current as long as your power supply is able to provide more than 0.8A (or at least exactly 0.8A but this is not recommended) at the required voltage or at all the required voltage range, which means, in practice, at the highest voltage of that range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the load draws a maximum current of 0.8A from 12V then your driver should be able to supply at least 0.8A. That's why your requirements say `should be able to supply at least 0.8A`. If you want to buy a tape measure to measure things up to 2 metres then you want your measure to be at least 2 meters long.

---

Your question is not a current-source-related one. No need to make it over-complicated.

- The title, `a constant current to a load regardless of load resistance`, is actually the definition of the ideal current source which has infinite output impedance and therefore infinite supply voltage.
- The current source you used in your simulation *(which I totally ignored initially but should be mentioned anyway. Thanks to [@V.V.T](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/689670/how-to-supply-a-constant-current-to-a-load-regardless-of-its-resistance/689693?noredirect=1#comment1837733_689693) for pointing this out.)* is not a current source. It's actually a strange voltage source configuration because the emitter will see one diode drop less than the Zener voltage at the base (neglecting the drop across the base resistance) thanks to the local feedback. This configuration would be a current source with a collector load.
- Using the op-amp's output as the main power source of the transistor-based configuration (even if it was a current source) is not a good idea because the constant current will be supplied from the op-amp's output and none of the ordinary op-amps will be able to source at least 0.8 Amps (except power op amp's which could be an overkill for your project).

If you want to use an op-amp as a voltage translator (to convert 3.3V to 12V) you don't have to build it as a non-inverting amplifier. Instead, a comparator configuration would work as well. Another option is to use transistors:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNRhoA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

---

The load is a motor and draws a good amount of current, so your best bet is to make your driver have as low output impedance as possible. One of the ways is to make a totem-pole driver:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3UpA6.png)</sup>

Important points for BJT totem pole:

- It is a voltage follower so V<sub>OUT</sub> = V<sub>IN</sub>. Make sure your 3.3V is translated to 12V before.
- Maximum collector-emitter voltage, V<sub>CE</sub> is a limiting factor (should be greater than 12V).
- Saturated collector-emitter voltage, V<sub>CE(sat)</sub>, is a limiting factor, and the maximum allowed continuous collector current, I<sub>C</sub>, is a limiting factor (should be greater than 0.8A).
- The product of the two above, P = V<sub>CE(sat)</sub> · I<sub>C</sub>, is the power dissipation and it should be less than the maximum power dissipation of the device, P<sub>tot</sub>. Consider heatsinking as well.

Important points for MOSFET totem pole:

- This is an **INVERTER** i.e. if you apply 0V to the input the output will be 12V *(If you have a simple single-transistor inverter to drive this section be aware that the input capacitance of the low-side MOSFET along with the pre-inverter's output impedance will basically slow down the switching action)*.
- Again, make sure the input voltage is translated to 12V. If you apply 3.3V directly and if it's above the threshold gate-source voltage (for both), V<sub>GS(th)</sub>, then both MOSFETs will turn on. Be careful.
- The voltage and current considerations apply here as well.
- Choosing the MOSFETs with low enough on-resistance, R<sub>DS(on)</sub>, is one of the key points. The high-side MOSFET will be supplying the load (by connecting 12V to the load) so make sure the conduction loss, P = I² R<sub>DS(on)</sub> is less than the MOSFET's maximum allowed power dissipation. Check the SOA graphs. Consider heatsinking.

Unless you are building an H-bridge the low-side MOSFET/BJT doesn't matter and may not be needed. But it's good to keep it there to tie the OUT to the ground (to keep the load grounded) when there's no input signal.

Comment: For the MOSFETs totem pole is it important to account for the ``Total Gate Charge`` and PWM frequency, in order to minimise the time when both MOSFETs might in their linear region and therefore having higher power dissipation (and possibly also shoot-through current if both MOSFETs are conducting)?

Comment: You sound very confident when you disprove `the most straightforward` finding that the project goal is `to drive such current regardless of the resistance`. Still, the question title is 'How to supply a constant current to a load regardless of its resistance?' and I believe it is also important to explain to the OP that `a basic setup with an NPN transistor and a zener diode`, which the OP found elsewhere, is not a constant current source at all. Especially important, 'cause none of prolific commenters mentions the fact.

Comment: @ChesterGillon that's a good point. Not only the total charge and PWM frequency but also the input capacitance (Ciss) should be taken into account. The MOSFET totem pole is an inverter, so if it's driven from a basic single-transistor inverter which has relatively high output impedance then the input capacitance along with pre-inverter's output impedance will basically slow down the turn-on and/or off. Shoot-through is another risk. I intentionally kept these out of scope in order to keep the post not too long. Thanks for the contribution.

Comment: 'This configuration would be a current source with a collector load': to be precise, a current sink.

Comment: And although almost certainly a current source circuit is irrelevant to OP's task, the OP does not reveal a current control method selected for their project, and further recommendations may vary. With the follow-up question this vague, a better option is to answer only the direct question, like the one posed in the title, and let the OP clarify details of 'the initial requirements' with the issuer of the task or, alternatively, study an abundant online offering of technical writing on stepper motor current control.

Answer (score 0):

You may receive a few advices on how you should understand `the initial requirements`, but the best option is to discuss this matter directly with the entity that `tasked` you with builing a circuit. What you, as a circuit designer, should certainly learn about current source configuration, regardless of whether this feature is necessary for this particular design, it is the circuit solution used to sink or source the constant current for a wide range of the load value.

#### CURRENT MIRROR

If you have never taken the Devices and Circuits (or similar name) course in your school, you can read about current mirrors in multiple online sources, including this portal. Here, I am drawing a prototype circuit, a sort of template for your development task:

[image: PNP CM]

The voltage source Vpulsed is what your voltage converter (`PWM signal amplifier`) could become when you comply with specifications for output power and stability. 'PWM signal amplifier' should be able to output the necessary current plus some margin. The current mirror is made with two pnp transistor, the resistor Rref defines the current that is replicated to the load. Qref and Qout are the generic pnp transistors, you should select the components that suits to your specifications.

The circuit is only basic, and your task is to add all the necessary components. First, the reference current cannot be made less than 800 mA, because the circuit **copies** the reference current. As the result, the circuit consumes extra power. You can multiply the replicated current using an asymmetric current mirror transistor pair: Gm ratio of transistors defines the multiplication factor. I demonstrate this improvement with the help of PMOS transistors: the Gm of generic MOS transistors in SPICE can be easily controlled with the MOS transistor parameter WIDTH ('w=1E3', 'w=1E5' of M1, M2 transistors).

[image: PMOS CM]

Iref in this circuit is one hundredth of Iout.

When learning about current mirror circuits you can find more sophisticated solutions.

Summing up, whether you need to use current mirrors in this design or you will resort to use of specialized integrated circuits for your stepper motor control circuit, current mirrors are an essential part of analog circuit design.

By the way, the transistor in your `transistor-based current source` contributes only insignificant part into the load current. Almost all the load current flows through R17 from LT1002 output.

Comment: What does the code markup (`like this`) in your answer mean? Does it indicate that something is a quotation?

Comment: Only that the meaning of highlighted words and phrases in this text is exactly identical with that of OP's question post; `PWM signal amplifier` and `transistor-based current source` are names of corresponding subcircuits given by OP, `the initial requirements` is how OP refers to the project goals;  in business administration parlance `tasked with` means 'assigned a task of`, the phrase is now infiltrating into a casual speech, do not mix up with an archaic 'to impose a tax on'.